# how to get memory usage for every request in grails application

Tags: java, grails, groovy, profiling, gvm

Are there any tools/plugins that can identify the profile like memory, cpu and other usage information on each request in grails web application.

Comment: Mainly i need to find  memory usage for each action in application.

Comment: Most of tools could show mem usage per method/class/etc, but it's really hard to distinguish which part of this belongs to which request, especially if you more that one simultaneous requests

Comment: have you looked into melody?  http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody

Comment: @IgorArtamonov suggest one tool for mem usage. i have tried grailsmelody for this, but it overrides grails datasource. so application is not running fine.

Comment: @cfrick melody overrides grails datasource. so application is not working fine. and show an error org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getInitialSize()

Comment: @AnIshA i was using only standard VisualVM, but there're other tools, like YouKit or JProfiler. can't say which is better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CrunchifyJVMParameters {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int mb = 1024 * 1024; 

        // get Runtime instance
        Runtime instance = Runtime.getRuntime();

        System.out.println("***** Heap utilization statistics [MB] *****\n");

        // available memory
        System.out.println("Total Memory: " + instance.totalMemory() / mb);

        // free memory
        System.out.println("Free Memory: " + instance.freeMemory() / mb);

        // used memory
        System.out.println("Used Memory: "
                + (instance.totalMemory() - instance.freeMemory()) / mb);

        // Maximum available memory
        System.out.println("Max Memory: " + instance.maxMemory() / mb);
    }
}
```

Source https://crunchify.com/java-runtime-get-free-used-and-total-memory-in-java/